# Find sample variance from sample mean and mean of squares

Tags: statistics

I have ten measurements like this:

[image]

and I have calculated the sample mean E(X) = 10.03, and the average of squares E(X^2) = 100.679:

[image]

Now I want to calculate the sample variance. I use the formula:

```
sample variance = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2 = 100.679 - (10.03)^2 = 0.0781
```

However, when using a calculator to calculate the variance, it gives the result `variance = 0.08678` instead.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What computer program did you use to calculate the variance?

Comment: I mean I used my calculator

Comment: but is my formula to calculate the variance correct?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought `0.8678` was the value you calculated. See @WillOrrick's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must multiply your result by $10/9$ if you want the sample variance to be an unbiased estimator of the population variance.  This is called [Bessel's correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction).